# Application Crashing at a particular point

Tags: iphone

I have a view with three buttons in an iphone app, want to go to another view by clicking a particular button, tried add target method, its working fine but when we go to next view after navigation and click on the back button their it crashes??

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    helpButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    helpButton.frame= CGRectMake(5, 370, 90, 30); 
    [helpButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Help"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    helpButton.tag=1;
    [self.view addSubview:helpButton];
}
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste some code here, paste the console output.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 
 [super viewDidLoad];
    
 helpButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 helpButton.frame= CGRectMake(5, 370, 90, 30);
 [helpButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Help"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 helpButton.tag=1;
 [self.view addSubview:helpButton];

Comment: Your app crashes in `viewDidLoad:` method?

Comment: When you press Back, it should not call viewDidLoad, as it is loaded and it is in the navigation stack. It should be viewDidAppear, something like that.

Comment: Oleg - viewDidLoad might be called again if low memory warnings previously caused the navigationController to unload any non-visible views :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I look at your code, it seems that your helpButton is a class variable... If it is true, you are missing a retain :

```
helpButton=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
```

not sure it will fix your problem, but it can help...

Comment: WTF??? This is a conventional constructor of UIButton, it should not be retained.

Comment: well if it's a member of the class, there's a chance that it might be released in class dealloc... it is just what I was pointing at.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help, actually i was doing a silly mistake, i was releasing the navigation controller object, anyways thanks once again for your help